# how to check some static string in python list?

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

I m checking full string  that is exists or not in list

Here is the code give below for checking the strings in list python

```
str_text = ['SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::ad4d7360-9c6c-44fa-bcbb-0db7e671e036.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END',
            'url was this SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::5e2650c2-728c-40af-99a4 
            eb100c432091.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END and click here to see details']

if 'SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::5e2650c2-728c-40af-99a4-eb100c432091.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END' in str_text:
       print('Exists')
```

i want to check both substrings `SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____:: & ____SERVER_UPLOAD_END` that exits in the `list` elements and also single list elements also contain both

Any Help would be Appreciated & thanks in Advance

Comment: yes i want to check both substrings ```SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____:: ``` and ```____SERVER_UPLOAD_END ```  that is exist in the list elements

Comment: yes i want to check both substrings in the list elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only checking if the given pattern exists in `str_text`. What you really want to do is check if the pattern exists in any of the strings contained in `str_text` list.

You would have to check in every string contained in the `str_text`. You should modify your code as below -

```
str_text = ['SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::ad4d7360-9c6c-44fa-bcbb-0db7e671e036.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END',
            'url was this SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::5e2650c2-728c-40af-99a4 eb100c432091.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END and click here to see details']

for strings in str_text:
    if 'SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::ad4d7360-9c6c-44fa-bcbb-0db7e671e036.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END' in strings:
       print('Exists')
```

A shorthand notation for the above code could be as follows -

```
str_text = ['SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::ad4d7360-9c6c-44fa-bcbb-0db7e671e036.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END',
            'url was this SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::5e2650c2-728c-40af-99a4 eb100c432091.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END and click here to see details']
pattern = 'SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::ad4d7360-9c6c-44fa-bcbb-0db7e671e036.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END'
print(*("Exists" for strings in str_text if pattern in strings ))
```

The above code would print `Exists` for each string in `str_text` that matches your required pattern. If you just want it printed once, you could just apply `break`  after the first match is found.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

You would have to do the contains check on every string in the list:

```
pat = 'SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::5e2650c2-728c-40af-99a4-eb100c432091.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END' in str_text

for s in str_text:
    if pat in s:
        print("Exists")
        break
```

There is a short-hand for that, `any`:

```
if any(pat in s for s in str_text):
    print("Exists")
```